# BigQuery error in load operation: Too many total leaf fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am uploading a big file into BigQuery, because it is too slow to operate on my own PC.

`bq --location=EU load --field_delimiter='\t' --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV single_cells.retinal_bipolar gs://single_cells/retinal-bipolar-neuron-drop-seq/exp_matrix.txt ./schema.json`

However, I got an error:

> BigQuery error in load operation: Too many total leaf fields: 27500

Indeed, the data has 27500 columns; doesn't BigQuery allow this?

Comment: There is a limit of 10,000 columns per table, as documented in [Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs). Depending on the size of the rows, maybe you can represent each row as just being a single `STRING` value...

Comment: I see. Thank you for pointing to this. In this case, I have to go without BigQuery and simply load the data into my memory to compute.

Comment: as Elliott pointed  - you can load your file into BigQuery table that is set with schema having ONLY one column of type STRING. Then (assuming that file and row size does not exceed [size limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs)) -  you will be able to use all power of BigQuery

Comment: Thanks, that's an idea. I will have a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another workaround - as Elliott pointed - you can load your file into BigQuery table that is set with schema having ONLY one column of type STRING. Then (assuming that file and row size does not exceed [`size limitations`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs)) - you will be able to use all power of BigQuery!

Answer (score 2):

The [Maximum columns per table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) value is 10,000 which means that the error message was thrown since the load job exceeded the maximum number of fields allowed in the schema.

Based on this, an available workaround is to split the table up into smaller tables in order to reduce the number of fields contained; In this way, you will be able to avoid this issue.