# BigQuery: Too many total leaf fields 10852

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I am importing some data from Google Cloud Datastore with about 980 columns. I have it exported first to Bucket and attempting to import it into BigQuery (using the [GCP guide here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities)). However, I get the error `Too many total leaf fields: 10852`.

I know for certain that none of the entities have more than 1000 fields. Is there a possibility that the import process is transforming my data and creating additional fields?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846726/bigquery-error-in-load-operation-too-many-total-leaf-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema's generated by the [Managed Import/Export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) service will not contain more than 10k fields.  So, it looks like you are importing into a BigQuery table that already has data.  BigQuery will take the union of the existing schema and the new schema.  So even if any given entity has less than 1000 fields, if the union of all field names in all your entities of a kind, plus the existing fields in the BigQuery schema.

Some options you have include:
1) Use a new table for each import into BigQuery.
2) Try using [projectionFields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore#cloud_datastore_export_service) to limit the fields loaded into BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks @jim morrison.
On further inspection, I did find that there were some fields that had an inordinately hight number of columns. 
I ended up using projectionFields as you suggested to export only a subset of the most important fields from my datastore backup.

Answer (score 0):

Jim Morrison's solution (using [projectionFields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore#cloud_datastore_export_service)) solved the issue for me.
I ended up passing a list of entity columns I was interested in and only exporting this subset to BigQuery. The following command line instruction achieves this.

```
bq --location=US load --source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP --projection_fields="field1, field4, field2, field3"  --replace mydataset.table gs://mybucket/2019-03-25T02:56:02_47688/default_namespace/kind_data/default_namespace_datakind.export_metadata
```